# Possible to make font size of iMessage on a Mac even larger via Terminal commands?

Tags: macos, fonts, accessibility

I enjoy messaging on iMessage. However, as I have poor eyesight, I find even the largest font size via the font slider limiting (screenshot with comparable font size in messages shown below):

[iMessage with slider scrolled all the way to the right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/954sd.png)

Is there a via Terminal commands in which I could affect the font size used in iMessage to be even larger than the one indicated via the slider?

Thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

Apple doesn't provide a [CLI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface) for Messages, so strictly speaking the answer to your question is no.

There is an open-source project which opens Messages in a web interface – there you can use the browser's zoom feature to get larger font size.

https://github.com/CamHenlin/iMessageWebClient

The issues is that this was put together 8 years ago, and most of its dependencies are out of support, so unless someone updates it, it is not a good long-term solution.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion and for linking the repo. While it is definitely a solution, I was hoping to make changes directly to the iMessage.

Comment: Messages are closed source, ie. it is up to Apple to add such a feature.

You can send Feedback or request support here: https://www.apple.com/feedback/messages-ios-ipados.html